# Android Popup Screen like in WhatsApp or Telegram

Tags: android, service, popup, lockscreen, whatsapp

I'm new in android developing.
I searched a lot for this and i didn't find any proper answer.
I want to make a Pop-up/Dialog Screen that Displays when something in a Service happens.

This Screen should be also available when the phone is locked.
What I already found is that you can make an Activity in Dialog Style or an Activity with a transparent background. But I don't think it's the right way to do that.
Here is one of those Screens (on the right): [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL9kG.jpg)

You can scroll through all the messages and respond to all of them.
My Debug phone has Android  4.0.2 (so it's API Level 14) and I want this to use as minimum Requirement for my App.

Edit:
Thanks for the reply, but I already tested the Notifications.
The problem is, that only the smallicon is shown in the notification bar.
I get no notification Window or Pop-up with a title or content...
So here is my implementation:

```
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.util.Log;

public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;


    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    public static final String TAG = "GCM test";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        if (!intent.getExtras().isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification("message:\n" + intent.getStringExtra("message"));
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_check)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText(msg);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, PopupMessageActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(PopupMessageActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: What language / environment are you using?

Comment: sorry... android-studio

Comment: Sorry, I use cordova - but @Meghdeep Ray's answer should help.

Answer (score 1):

Notifications are what you're looking for

Here's the link to the android developer page for it :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Toasts are also likely what might help you :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Good luck !

Comment: @Signare Yes. Ofcourse depending on the length you set it to.

Answer (score 0):

You are Talking about App Widget That runs on the `lockscreen` 
.. so u can read this page and use this
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html